# c# No Overload for 'állemail_CheckedChanged' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Tags: c#

Fairly new to C# and been bashing my way through changing some code written for me to add enhancements to a software program I have had written.

I am trying to expand some code so that I have a check box to show all emails.  The code itself is fine but i get the error No Overload for 'állemail_CheckedChanged' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Below is the code.  Any ideas on what this is caused by and how to fix it?

```
    public void allemail_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e, DataTable dtEmailConfiguration, string Uid, string CompId, string Email)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {
            CompanyId = CompId;
            UserId = Uid;
            button3.Visible = true;
            btnCheckAll.Visible = true;
            dtEmailConfig = dtEmailConfiguration;
            foreach (DataRow o in dtEmailConfig.Select("Name = 'pop3'"))
            {
                //  Console.WriteLine("\t" + o["HostName"] + "\t" + o["Port"] + "\t" + o["Username"] + "\t" + o["Password"]);
                HostName = Convert.ToString(o["HostName"]);
                Port = Convert.ToString(o["Port"]);
                UserName = Convert.ToString(o["Username"]);
                Password = Convert.ToString(o["Password"]);
            }
            foreach (DataRow o in dtEmailConfig.Select("Name = 'imap'"))
            {
                //  Console.WriteLine("\t" + o["HostName"] + "\t" + o["Port"] + "\t" + o["Username"] + "\t" + o["Password"]);

                HostName = Convert.ToString(o["HostName"]);
                Port = Convert.ToString(o["Port"]);
                UserName = Convert.ToString(o["Username"]);
                Password = Convert.ToString(o["Password"]);
            }
            foreach (DataRow o in dtEmailConfig.Select("Hostname = 'pop-mail.outlook.com'"))
            {
                //  Console.WriteLine("\t" + o["HostName"] + "\t" + o["Port"] + "\t" + o["Username"] + "\t" + o["Password"]);
                HostName = Convert.ToString(o["HostName"]);
                Port = Convert.ToString(o["Port"]);
                UserName = Convert.ToString(o["Username"]);
                Password = Convert.ToString(o["Password"]);
            }
            //clear existing data grid
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;

            table = null;
            EmailLoc = Email;
            table.Columns.Add("From", typeof(String));
            table.Columns.Add("Subject", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Email Date", typeof(DateTime));
            table.Columns.Add("Count Attachment", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("UIDL", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("MetaData", typeof(object));
            GetEmailFromEmailServer(HostName, Port, UserName, Password);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionHelper.LogFile(ex.Message, ex.ToString(), System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, this.FindForm().Name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show the line the code is actually failing on.

Comment: the actual error takes me to this code in the desigener file

"this.allemail.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.allemail_CheckedChanged);"

Answer (score 3):

You've changed the function signature of `allemail_CheckedChanged` away from what it was. That's not how delegates/handlers work. They need the fixed signature that is prescribed by the delegate, in this case you need to change it back to `allemail_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`.

You'll have to find another way to get the values of the other arguments you want to pass, for instance by making them class members of your form. Without seeing the rest of your code, it's hard to be exact.

---

Note: 
It's also really odd to have `InitializeComponent` called from the event handler -- this method should be called exactly once in the constructor for your form.